# If $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly convergent, and $\|f_n-f_{n-1}\|_\infty<c\|f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}\|_\infty+b\| g_{n-1}-g_{n-2}\|_\infty$, does $\{f_n\}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

> The sequence of function $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly convergent, and the sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ satisfies the following condition,
> $$\| f_n-f_{n-1}\|_\infty<c\,\| f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}\|_\infty+b\,\| g_{n-1}-g_{n-2}\|_\infty$$ $0<c<1$ and $0<b<1$. Is the sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ converge?

I would be thankful if someone could give me a hint about this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this false even for sequences of numbers?  Try
$$
f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k},\qquad g_k = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}
$$
with $c=b=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, awesome counterexample.